# Recusively merge AND sort two linked lists into a third in reverse order

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, reverse, mergesort

I'm trying to write **a single function** in Java (`Node sortedmerge(Node node1, Node node2)`) where the data in `node1` and `node2` are already sorted in descending order ({5, 3, 1, 0}). I figured out an implementation for the function but I can't figure out how to make it recursive:

```
//Defined elsewhere as a global variable
static Node<Integer> head = new Node();
//Used to store the final sorted linked list

Node sortedmerge(Node node1, Node node2) {

    // if both the nodes are null
    if (node1 == null && node2 == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // if both of them have nodes present traverse them
    while (node1 != null && node2 != null) {

        // Now compare both nodes current data
        if (node1.data <= node2.data) {
            Node temp = node1.next;
            node1.next = head;
            head = node1;
            node1 = temp;
        } else {
            Node temp = node2.next;
            node2.next = head;
            head = node2;
            node2 = temp;
        }
    }

    // If second list reached end, but first list has
    // nodes. Add remaining nodes of first list at the
    // front of result list
    while (node1 != null) {
        Node temp = node1.next;
        node1.next = head;
        head = node1;
        node1 = temp;
    }

    // If first list reached end, but second list has
    // node. Add remaining nodes of first list at the
    // front of result list
    while (node2 != null) {
        Node temp = node2.next;
        node2.next = head;
        head = node2;
        node2 = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

*supposedly* there's a way to do it without a temporary node (`Node temp`) or any outside functions... but at this point I'd just be happy to make it function recursively (I'm struggling to understand how to implement recursive calls).

Answer (score 0):

Your function merges two sorted lists, you can implement this with a loop as posted or recursively as will be shown below. Note however that:

- there is no reason to make `head` a global variable. You should instead define it as a local and return as the return value of the function.
- the `head` in your code does not point to the head of the list, but to the last element, aka the tail node.
- once one of the lists is exhausted, you can just append the other to the last element of the merged list.
- a recursive implementation of `sortedmerge` will require stack space proportional to the length of the merged list, which can easily exceed available stack space, causing a **stack overflow** exception.

Here is a simple recursive implementation:

```java
Node sortedmerge(Node node1, Node node2) {

    // if either node is null, return the other node
    if (node1 == null) {
        return node2;
    }
    if (node2 == null) {
        return node1;
    }

    // select the node with the largest data
    if (node1.data <= node2.data) {
        // select node2 and append the rest of the merged list to it
        node2.next = sortedmerge(node1, node2.next);
        return node2;
    } else {
        // select node1 and append the rest of the merged list to it
        node1.next = sortedmerge(node1.next, node2);
        return node1;
    }
}
```